# How to assign and retrieve value from settings file in ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using ruby 2.1.5 and rails 3.2.13.I need to use an array of values in two place namely in `_index.html.haml` and `helper_file.rb`.

```
array = ['cat','dog','lion','tiger','elephant']
```

I want to know how to handle this with out assign this array in two files. I am looking for a settings file where i need to save this array and get the value from that settings file to use in both `_index.html.haml` and `helper_file.rb` file.

Need help to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a file in `config/initializers` with name like `constants.rb` and assign values there like:

```
ARRAY = ['cat','dog','lion','tiger','elephant']
```

then in the site you can use this array. All the constants are written in caps as per the naming convention so please take care of that. And we keep the file in initializer so that it loads while the application is loaded. Also you can assign those values to `ENV` variable using the same initializer file like this:

```
ENV['ARRAY'] =  ['cat','dog','lion','tiger','elephant']
```

Also you can make array with keys. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. How to access ENV['ARRAY'] in my _index.html.haml from constants.rb.

Comment: Just type `ENV['ARRAY']` you will get the value